# '@' sign in react JS package import

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have seen 2 types of Import statements:

```
import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native'
import {NavigationiContainer} from '@react-navigation/native'
```

One is imported from 'import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native'
import {NavigationiContainer} from '@react-navigation/native' and other is from'@react-navigation/native'
, what does '@' sign means here?

Comment: This has nothing to do with React or JavaScript itself. It's how npm identifies certain kinds of packages.

Comment: Check this for more information https://docs.npmjs.com/about-scopes